# how to redirect to the same url, when form validation errors in update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, redirect

Is it possible when validation to make redirect to same url (site.com/posts/1/edit), keeping the previously entered data? not to (site.com/posts/)

I mean

site.com/posts/1/edit    --->   validate failed  --->  site.com/posts/1/edit

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following snippet:

```
    def update
        @post= Post.new(params[:post])
        if @post.valid?
          redirect_to valid_path
        else
          render action: "edit"
        end
    end
```

If the user isn't valid rails will render the edit page again. The form values will be filled again if you used form_for @post

Comment: ```render action: "edit"``` won't make your url look like ```.../edit```

Comment: The main requirement was to keep the entered data and not to backup the url path which is only possible with an ajax validation request or a redirect and flashes to hold the values.